# MYSQL request from two tables with CONCAT

Tags: mysql, sql, request, database-table

maybe you can help me:

If have a table1: accounts

```
user_id   account_id   
39        3799207
39        80286966
40        3789458
```

...

table2: subscribers

```
id   client_id  master_id   master_account_id   active 
1    43         39          3799207             1
2    43         39          80286966            1
3    44         39          80286966            1
4    45         39          80286966            1
```

...

Using this request:

```
'SELECT account_id FROM accounts WHERE user_id = "39"';
```

I can get this table:

```
Account
3799207
80286966
```

How can I get this table:

```
Account      Subscribers     Count
3799207      43              1
80286966     43,44,45...     3
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.account_id Account, 
      GROUP_CONCAT(b.client_id) Subscribers,
      COUNT(b.client_id) `Count`
FROM accounts a INNER JOIN subscribers b
    on a.account_id = b.master_account_id
WHERE b.master_id = '39'
GROUP BY a.account_id
```

`MySQl` and `SQLite` has builtin function `GROUP_CONCAT` which concactenates columns into rows.

HTH